# Error “unable to complete previous operation due to low memory ” whenever i upload image using camera app in my android smart phone

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

whenever I upload an image to react website using my mobile's camera app the webpage refreshes and gives "unable to complete previous operation due to low memory " error. My phone's has 4GB ram

this is the input which is concerned with uploading image

```
<StyledMenuItem>
            <label htmlFor="avatar">Upload Photo</label>
            <input type="file" accept="image/*,capture=camera" capture="camera" id="avatar" onChange={onFileSelectHandler} style={{display: 'none'}} /> 
</StyledMenuItem>
```

this is the function which handles the changes for input

```
const onFileSelectHandler = (e) => {
    handleClose();
    const payload = new FormData();
    payload.append('image', e.target.files[0]);
    updateUserProfilePicture(payload);
  };
```

and this is the function which uploads the image to the api

```
export const updateUserProfilePicture = (image) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await Api.put('/user/pictureUpdate', image);
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_USER_PROFILE_PICTURE,
      payload: res.data.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return;
  }
};
```

Comment: I have the same problem, tried to compress the image and even use base64. Nothing has worked to handle the pictures coming from the camera. Have you found a solution/worrkaround?

Comment: Any luck in resolving the issue - either of you?